spotipy API base-62 error for adding track to playlist
I'm running into an error using the spotipy package. It seems to say that the playlist ID or track ID isn't valid, but I can visit the link to both and they work. Unsure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.
import requests
import os
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

os.environ['SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID'] = '$MY_CLIENT_ID'
os.environ['SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET'] = '$MY_CLIENT_SECRET'
os.environ['SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI'] = 'http://localhost'

scope = "playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private user-library-modify"
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(scope=scope))
sp.playlist_add_items('7AatTbqsTPhQ4bTRDqXaQH', '6nz35DNIzbtj5ztpDEcW1j')

This gives the following error:
sp.playlist_add_items('7AatTbqsTPhQ4bTRDqXaQH', '6nz35DNIzbtj5ztpDEcW1j')

HTTP Error for POST to https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/7AatTbqsTPhQ4bTRDqXaQH/tracks with Params: {'position': None} returned 400 due to Invalid base62 id
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 271, in _internal_call
    response.raise_for_status()
  File ".../.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/7AatTbqsTPhQ4bTRDqXaQH/tracks

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 1085, in playlist_add_items
    return self._post(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 328, in _post
    return self._internal_call("POST", url, payload, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 293, in _internal_call
    raise SpotifyException(
spotipy.exceptions.SpotifyException: http status: 400, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/7AatTbqsTPhQ4bTRDqXaQH/tracks:
 Invalid base62 id, reason: None

I've also tried running:
sp.playlist_add_items('spotify:playlist:7AatTbqsTPhQ4bTRDqXaQH', 'spotify:track:6nz35DNIzbtj5ztpDEcW1j')

And received URI errors.
I also tried defining tracks as a list and passing it through and got the same error as above:
tracks = ['6nz35DNIzbtj5ztpDEcW1j']
sp.playlist_add_items('7AatTbqsTPhQ4bTRDqXaQH', tracks[0])


It may be due to missing API parameter or parameter value format. Check the API doc from here:

Example format and value is this:
sp.playlist_add_items(playlist_id = your_playlist_id, items =['spotify:episode:3nwfTNjbhDu8Cnp81TdmGO'], position=None)

So in this line of your code parameter names are missing:
sp.playlist_add_items('7AatTbqsTPhQ4bTRDqXaQH', '6nz35DNIzbtj5ztpDEcW1j')

Correct way is this:
sp.playlist_add_items(playlist_id = '7AatTbqsTPhQ4bTRDqXaQH', items =['6nz35DNIzbtj5ztpDEcW1j'], position=None)

Also check the discussion here.

Ah, this helped. It turned out, it wasn't that I needed the parameter names, but rather I pass in a list instead of values from that list.
So this worked
tracks = ['6nz35DNIzbtj5ztpDEcW1j']
sp.playlist_add_items('7AatTbqsTPhQ4bTRDqXaQH', tracks)


This code will work.
username = sp.me()['id']
sp.user_playlist_add_tracks(username, '7AatTbqsTPhQ4bTRDqXaQH', ['6nz35DNIzbtj5ztpDEcW1j'])

playlist_add_items() is the wrong API.
user_playlist_add_tracks() is correct API.


Result

